# Application consistently dropping connection every hour or so

Tags: heroku, connection

I'm running a Discord bot on Heroku and every hour or so (Not designated cycling which is every night), the bot loses connection and has to reconnect to the Discord API. Why does this happen? Can it be fixed?

Comment: If you are on free tier you get free dynos and, they sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: But the Discord API uses heartbeat. Isn't that technically constantly active?

Comment: Also, just double-checked. Only web nodes sleep. Not worker nodes. And my bot is running on a worker node.